# ES6 Promise wait for K out N promises to resolve

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```js
var p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
  setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 'one'); 
});
var p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
  setTimeout(resolve, 2000, 'two'); 
});
var p3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 3000, 'three');
});

Promise.all([p1,p2,p3]).then(values => { 
  console.log(values);
}, reason => {
  console.log(reason)
});
```

How can i wait for 2 promises to get completed ? Promise.race() wait for one promise to get completed.

## Edit

I have n number of promises, what i want to achieve is wait for first k number of promises to get resolved and than trigger some event. assume **k < n**

## Edit - 2

I am sure that k number of promise will be successfully resolved out of n numbers of promise given

Comment: You're question is unclear, please revise with more relevant information

Comment: How about `Promise.race([Promise.all([p1, p2]), Promise.all([p2, p3]), Promise.all([p1, p3])])`?

Comment: @Bergi I thought of that, but it's not very generic and assumes he only has 3 (he may just be using 3 for this example).

Comment: And how should a rejection be handled in this scenario? first rejection == fail or silent fails untill the result can't be achieved anymore?

Comment: we can discard the failure scenario. we are sure that k number of promise will be successfully resolved out of n numbers of promise given

Comment: This should be reflected in the question then.

Comment: @xyz the question is not just wether enough promises will be resolved, the question is how to handle if even a single one fails.

Comment: @JLRishe It could easily be made generic, but it has horrible performance - that's why I only posted it as a comment

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(**Note:** Bluebird has a [built-in helper function](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.some.html) that serves precisely this purpose and has more or less the same behavior as my `waitForN` method below, so that option is always available)

I don't believe ES6 promises have an elegant built-in way to do this, but you could define the following <s>relatively short</s> *now somewhat long* helper function to take care of this.

**Edit:** Added an additional helper function that includes the indices of the successful promises in the result.

**Edit:** Updated to reject if the number of rejections reaches the point where successful resolution would be impossible.

**Edit:** Updated to more gracefully work with `promises` if it is iterable and check edge cases where the result should immediately resolve (e.g. if `n === 0`)

```js
function waitForN(n, promises) {
    let resolved = [];
    let failCount = 0;
    let pCount = 0;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const checkSuccess = () => {
            if (resolved.length >= n) { resolve(resolved); }
        };
        const checkFailure = () => {
            if (failCount + n > pCount) {
                reject(new Error(`Impossible to resolve successfully. n = ${n}, promise count = ${pCount}, failure count = ${failCount}`));
            }
        };

        for (let p of promises) {
            pCount += 1;

            Promise.resolve(p).then(r => {
                if (resolved.length < n) { resolved.push(r); }
                checkSuccess();
            }, () => {
                failCount += 1;
                checkFailure();
            });
        }

        checkFailure();
        checkSuccess();
    });
}

const waitForNWithIndices = (n, promises) =>
    waitForN(n, promises.map((p, index) => 
        Promise.resolve(p).then(result => ({ index, result }))
    ));

var p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
  setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 'one'); 
});
var p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
  setTimeout(resolve, 2000, 'two'); 
});
var p3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 3000, 'three');
});
var p4 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 1500, 'four');
});

waitForN(2, [p1,p2,p3,p4]).then(values => { 
  console.log(values);
}, reason => {
  console.log(reason)
});

waitForNWithIndices(2, [p1,p2,p3,p4]).then(values => { 
  console.log(values);
}, reason => {
  console.log(reason)
});
```

Comment: Doesn't provide any way to know which result is which.  Might be a little hard to use for that reason.  Other than that, it looks like it would work.

Comment: You really should not ignore rejections. If you don't want to reject on the first one, you at least have to reject when there are no longer enough promises for N fulfillments. You also will need to reject when `N < promises.length`.

Comment: @jfriend00 If he did want to match up the results with the original values they came from, there are a variety of different ways one could imagine going about that, but I've included an example of how one could include the indices of the successful promises (relative to the initial array) in the result.

Comment: @Bergi I changed it to ignore rejections based on OP's comment: _"we can discard the failure scenario. we are sure that k number of promise will be successfully resolved out of n numbers of promise given"_, but you're right, I'll modify it as you suggested.

Comment: I would also recommend to take any iterable (like `Promise.all` does) and not use `.forEach`.

Comment: @Bergi Ok, fair point. I've modified it to use `for...of` instead of `.forEach` (and add the rejection logic you suggested), but it still assumes that `promises` has a `.length` property with the correct value. Not sure of a good way around that  aside from coercing it to an array right away with `Array.from()`.

Comment: `Array.from` might do, but you could also just put a count inside the loop and `reject()` in the end (if using `resolved[i] = r` instead of `push` you'd need that anyway). Also, `Promise.resolve(p).then(…)` for extra points :-)

Comment: @Bergi I'm not sure what you mean by "and `reject()` in the end". Could you clarify?

Comment: @JLRishe Doing the "length" check after the loop has counted the elements. Basically you'll need to run the success and error checks after the loop (which also accounts for cases like `N == 0` that should immediately fulfill).

Comment: @Bergi Ah, that's clearer. Thanks. I'm still not sure I would use `resolved[i] = r` because that would create a sparse array and people don't tend to like sparse arrays (unless I'm still missing something there?)

Comment: I think the sparse array would be a cleaner solution than the `waitForNWithIndices`, but it depends a lot on use case

Comment: @Bergi I'm not a huge fan of my `waitForNWithIndices` (added it to fulfill jfriend00's suggestion) but personally I'd be even less keen on a sparse array. Probably better to leave it up to the person utilizing the helper function to prepackage any associated values they need with the resolution values: `let ps = urls.map(url => fetchItem(url).then(item => ({ item, url }))); waitForN(2, ps).then(urlsAndItems => /* use them */);` Also, comparing this to Bluebird's `.some()` method, that doesn't use a sparse array or provide any way to get at the original values.

Comment: @JLRishe It would be great if you can keep the old unpolished code too, so that novice like me can track the differences and learn from it

Comment: @xyz You can see all of the transformations this answer has gone through, and my original answer, by clicking the [edited X mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48129233/revisions) link under my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a higher order function to bake in the `n` then run all promises waiting for `n` to finish

```js
var p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
  setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 'one'); 
});
var p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
  setTimeout(resolve, 2000, 'two'); 
});
var p3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 3000, 'three');
});

const raceN = n => (...promises) => {
  const resolved = []
  return new Promise((res, rej) =>
    promises.forEach(promise => 
      promise.then(x => {
        resolved.push(x)
        if (resolved.length === n)
          res(resolved)
      })
      .catch(rej)
    )
  )
}

const race2 = raceN(2)
race2(p1, p2, p3)
  .then(results => console.log(results))
  
race2(Promise.resolve('resolved'), Promise.reject('rejected'))
  .then(results => console.log(results))
  .catch(reason => console.log(reason))
```

Comment: Aside from being curried, and using `...` this looks almost exactly like my answer from 13 minutes ago. Not saying you copied me, but I kinda beat you to it.

Comment: I did handle rejection (see the edit history). I deliberately removed it because OP said s/he wants to ignore rejections.

Comment: @JLRishe at some point it becomes impossible to resolve, you have 3 promises and 2 reject then you can never resolve with 2.

Comment: @HMR Yes, OP said that in their case it was guaranteed that at least N promises would succeed, but I have just modified my answer to reject at the point that a successful resolution becomes impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Given my many comments on JLRishe's answer, I'll also post my subtly different version of the function:

```
function any(k, iterable) {
    const results = [];
    let fullfilled = 0, rejected = 0, n = 0;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        k = Math.max(0, Math.floor(k));
        function check() {
            if (fulfilled == k)
                resolve(results);
            else if (rejected + k == n + 1)
                reject(new Error(`No ${k} of ${n} got fulfilled`));
        }

        for (const thenable of iterable) {
            const i = n++;
            Promise.resolve(thenable).then(res => {
                if (fulfilled++ < k) results[i] = res;
                check();
            }, () => {
                rejected++;
                check();
            });
        }
        check();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but maybe this will do it for you:

```
const first = howMany => (promises,resolved=[],rejected=[]) => {
  if(promises.length-rejected.length<howMany){
    return Promise.reject([resolved,rejected]);
  }
  if(resolved.length===howMany){
    return Promise.resolve(resolved);
  }
  if(resolved.length===0&&rejected.length===0){
    promises=promises.map(
      (p,index)=>Promise.resolve(p)
        .then(resolve=>[resolve,index])
        .catch(err=>Promise.reject([err,index]))
    );
  }
  return Promise.race(promises)
  .then(
    ([resolve,index])=>
      first(howMany)(
        promises.filter(
          (p,i)=>i!==index
        ),
        resolved.concat([resolve]),
        rejected
      )
  )
  .catch(
    ([err,index])=>
    first(howMany)(
      promises.filter(
        (p,i)=>i!==index
      ),
      resolved,
      rejected.concat([err])
    )  
  );
};

const first2 = first(2);
first2([p1,p2,p3])
.then(
  result=>//you will have an array of 2 with resolve value(s)
)
.catch(
  err=>//you will have 2 arrays, resolved ones and errors
)
```

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT: Updated to match question edits.*

Pretty easy to roll your own when the abstraction limits your expressiveness.

This code is short and can easily be reworked to run in legacy ES3 environments.

You can also easily expand its usefulness by adding code to cancel unresolved timeouts. This is what you get when you don't hand everything over to a library; greater simplicity and more capability.

```
function raceN(n, fns, resolve, reject) {
  const res = [], rej = [];
  let halt = false;

  for (const [idx, fn] of fns.entries()) {
    fn(data => update(res, data, idx), data => update(rej, data, idx));
  }
  function update(arr, data, idx) {
    if (halt) return;
    arr.push({idx, data});

    if ((halt=res.length >= n)) resolve(res);
    else if ((halt=rej.length > fns.length - n)) reject(rej);
  }
}
```

***DEMO:***

```js
function raceN(n, fns, resolve, reject) {
  const res = [], rej = [];
  let halt = false;

  for (const [idx, fn] of fns.entries()) {
    fn(data => update(res, data, idx), data => update(rej, data, idx));
  }
  function update(arr, data, idx) {
    if (halt) return;
    arr.push({idx, data});

    if ((halt=res.length >= n)) resolve(res);
    else if ((halt=rej.length > fns.length - n)) reject(rej);
  }
}



function rand() { return Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5000) }

var fns = [(resolve, reject) => { 
  setTimeout(resolve, rand(), 'one'); 
}, 
(resolve, reject) => { 
  setTimeout(resolve, rand(), 'two'); 
}, 
(resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(reject, rand(), 'three');
}];

raceN(2, fns, values => { 
  console.log("SUCCESS:", values);
}, reason => {
  console.log("REJECT:", reason)
});
```

---

If you're guaranteed that at least `n` elements will succeed, it then becomes even shorter and simpler.

```
function raceN(n, fns, resolve, reject) {
  const res = [];
  for (const [idx, fn] of fns.entries()) {
    fn(data => res.length < n && res.push({idx, data}) == n) && resolve(res),
       data => reject({idx, data}));
  }
}
```

***DEMO:***

```js
function raceN(n, fns, resolve, reject) {
  const res = [];

  for (const [idx, fn] of fns.entries()) {
    fn(data => res.length < n && res.push({idx, data}) == n) && resolve(res),
       data => reject({idx, data}));
  }
}



function rand() { return Math.ceil(Math.random() * 4000) }

var fns = [(resolve, reject) => { 
  setTimeout(resolve, rand(), 'one'); 
}, 
(resolve, reject) => { 
  setTimeout(resolve, rand(), 'two'); 
}, 
(resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(reject, rand(), 'three');
}];

raceN(2, fns, values => { 
  console.log("SUCCESS:", values);
}, reason => {
  console.log("REJECTING:", reason)
});
```

Comment: Ok, but OP's question is about promises whereas this results in N separate calls to a callback function (the one that logs "SUCCESS"). (**Edit:** as I was making my comment, you edited your answer to call the callback function once.) Is there any reason you didn't craft your answer to apply to promises?

Comment: @JLRishe: The answer is now updated for the clarified requirements (**Edit:** as you noticed ;-) ). I gave this solution for the same reason that people provide native DOM API solutions to jQuery questions. It requires nothing more in the environment to solve the problem.

Comment: Given that Promises are now a standard part of JavaScript (and can be polyfilled in older engines), I don't think the jQuery analogy is entirely apt, but ok.

Comment: @JLRishe: I agree, from the perspective of adding dependencies. But they're similar in that they're library abstractions. Any time you relegate responsibilities to library code, you limit yourself to what that library permits, and can often end up writing less clear code to solve the same problem. I personally don't often find Promise code to be an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

One other idea could be using `Promise.reject()` to cut it short when the condition is met while catching possible errors thrown, could be as follows;

```js
var p1 = new Promise((v, x) =>  setTimeout(v, 1000, 'one')),
    p2 = new Promise((v, x) =>  setTimeout(v, 5000, 'two')),
    p3 = new Promise((v, x) =>  setTimeout(v, 1500, 'three')),
    pn = (n, ps, k = 0, r = []) => Promise.all(ps.map(p => p.then(v => (k === n - 1 ? Promise.reject(r.concat(v))
                                                                                    : (++k, r.push(v))))))
                                          .catch(r => Array.isArray(r) ? r : Promise.reject(r));

pn(2,[p1,p2,p3]).then(rs => console.log(rs))
                .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Answer (score 0):

A more modern approach, in 2022, using [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops) library:

```
import {pipeAsync, take, waitRace} from 'iter-ops';

// easy-to-read way to define a job function:
const job = (delay, value) => new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(value), delay);
});

// list of jobs:
const input = [
    job(1000, 'one'),
    job(2000, 'two'),
    job(3000, 'three')
];

const i = pipeAsync(
    input, // our input
    waitRace(10), // race-resolve with cache up to 10 items
    take(2) // take only the first 2 items
).catch(err => {
    console.log(err); // report any iteration-time error
});

// iterating through our list of jobs:
(async function () {
    for await(const a of i) {
        console.log(a);
    }
})();
```

This will output `one` and `two`. You can twist the delays to see the result change accordingly.

**CREDITS**

I am the author of the library, while operator [waitRace](https://vitaly-t.github.io/iter-ops/functions/waitRace.html) was implemented by [@Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi).